# `impyla` connecting to Hive on Dataproc: impala.error.HiveServer2Error: Invalid OperationHandle: OperationHandle

Tags: hive, google-cloud-dataproc, impyla

I'm using `impyla` to connect to Hive in Dataproc. The connection is created this way

```
        conn = impala.dbapi.connect(
            host=host,
            port=10000,
            user=None,
            password=None,
            auth_mechanism='PLAIN',
            use_ssl=False,
        )
```

This connection does not need username and password. I'm able to use `pyhive` and `pyodbc` to connect and do queries with intermittent success. Using `impyla`, it is able to connect and go some steps, but has always failed after establishing connection. The log below shows details.

This always fails, hence more predictable than the `pyhive` and `pyodbc` cases. I hope this is some configuration issue that can be fixed, after which maybe it will give me less headache than `pyhive` and `pyodbc`.

Any pointers? Thanks!

```
pyhive_client: impyla

[2021-03-13 01:28:00.451 US/Pacific; INFO; vale.sql._hive, init, 420] using Hive client "impyla"
[2021-03-13 01:28:01.243 US/Pacific; INFO; vale.gcp._dataproc, create_cluster, 523] creating cluster "test-sql-hive-debug" ...
[2021-03-13 01:33:10.712 US/Pacific; INFO; vale.gcp._dataproc, create_cluster, 535] cluster "test-sql-hive-debug" created
[2021-03-13 01:33:11.854 US/Pacific; INFO; vale.sql._hive, _get_host, 713] using cluster "test-sql-hive-debug" at 10.22.174.52
[2021-03-13 01:33:11.854 US/Pacific; INFO; vale.sql._hive, connect, 560] connecting to Hive server 10.22.174.52 ...
[2021-03-13 01:33:11.854 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, connect, 789] Connecting to HiveServer2 10.22.174.52:10000 with PLAIN authentication mechanism
[2021-03-13 01:33:11.854 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala._thrift_api, get_socket, 109] get_socket: host=10.22.174.52 port=10000 use_ssl=False ca_cert=None
[2021-03-13 01:33:11.854 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, connect, 822] sock=<thriftpy2.transport.socket.TSocket object at 0x7fb7b4e18f50>
[2021-03-13 01:33:11.855 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala._thrift_api, get_transport, 180] get_transport: socket=<thriftpy2.transport.socket.TSocket object at 0x7fb7b4e18f50> host=10.22.174.52 kerberos_service_name=impala auth_mechanism=PLAIN user=None password=fuggetaboutit
[2021-03-13 01:33:11.856 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala._thrift_api, get_transport, 189] get_transport: user=root
[2021-03-13 01:33:11.856 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala._thrift_api, get_transport, 196] get_transport: password=password
[2021-03-13 01:33:12.079 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, connect, 835] transport=<thrift_sasl.TSaslClientTransport object at 0x7fb7b4e18c50> protocol=<thriftpy2.protocol.binary.TBinaryProtocol object at 0x7fb7b4e18cd0> service=<thriftpy2.thrift.TClient object at 0x7fb7b4e18650>
[2021-03-13 01:33:12.080 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, init, 58] HiveServer2Connection(service=<impala.hiveserver2.HS2Service object at 0x7fb7b4e18c10>, default_db=None)
[2021-03-13 01:33:12.080 US/Pacific; INFO; vale.sql._hive, connect, 571] ... connected to Hive server 10.22.174.52
[2021-03-13 01:33:12.080 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, cursor, 117] Getting a cursor (Impala session)
[2021-03-13 01:33:12.080 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, cursor, 122] .cursor(): getting new session_handle
[2021-03-13 01:33:12.080 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _log_request, 1031] OpenSession: req=TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol=5, username='root', password=None, configuration=None)
[2021-03-13 01:33:12.081 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _execute, 1006] Attempting to open transport (tries_left=3)
[2021-03-13 01:33:12.081 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _execute, 1008] Transport opened
[2021-03-13 01:33:12.272 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _log_response, 1034] OpenSession: resp=TOpenSessionResp(status=TStatus(statusCode=0, infoMessages=None, sqlState=None, errorCode=None, errorMessage=None), serverProtocolVersion=5, sessionHandle=TSessionHandle(sessionId=THandleIdentifier(guid=b'\xbb4\x1d\xe6\x08\x08Mw\xb4\xafu\xbcO\xab\xe9B', secret=b'\xd9>\r\xdc\x9d\x15Kk\xb9K\xc13\r\x1d\x9a\xd0')), configuration={'hive.server2.thrift.resultset.default.fetch.size': '1000'})
[2021-03-13 01:33:12.272 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, cursor, 129] HiveServer2Cursor(service=<impala.hiveserver2.HS2Service object at 0x7fb7b4e18c10>, session_handle=TSessionHandle(sessionId=THandleIdentifier(guid=b'\xbb4\x1d\xe6\x08\x08Mw\xb4\xafu\xbcO\xab\xe9B', secret=b'\xd9>\r\xdc\x9d\x15Kk\xb9K\xc13\r\x1d\x9a\xd0')), default_config={'hive.server2.thrift.resultset.default.fetch.size': '1000'}, hs2_protocol_version=5)
[2021-03-13 01:33:12.272 US/Pacific; DEBUG; vale.sql._sql, execute, 51] executing SQL statement:
SHOW DATABASES
args:
()
kwargs:
{}
[2021-03-13 01:33:12.273 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, execute_async, 356] Executing query SHOW DATABASES
[2021-03-13 01:33:12.273 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _debug_log_state, 386] _execute_async: self._buffer=Batch() self._description=None self._last_operation_active=False self._last_operation=None
[2021-03-13 01:33:12.273 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _reset_state, 296] _reset_state: Resetting cursor state
[2021-03-13 01:33:12.273 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _debug_log_state, 386] _execute_async: self._buffer=Batch() self._description=None self._last_operation_active=False self._last_operation=None
[2021-03-13 01:33:12.274 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _log_request, 1031] ExecuteStatement: req=TExecuteStatementReq(sessionHandle=TSessionHandle(sessionId=THandleIdentifier(guid=b'\xbb4\x1d\xe6\x08\x08Mw\xb4\xafu\xbcO\xab\xe9B', secret=b'\xd9>\r\xdc\x9d\x15Kk\xb9K\xc13\r\x1d\x9a\xd0')), statement='SHOW DATABASES', confOverlay={'hive.auto.convert.join': 'false', 'hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask': 'false', 'hive.bfd.odd.reducers': 'true', 'hive.cli.print.header': 'true', 'hive.exec.max.created.files': '500000', 'hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode': '1000000', 'hive.exec.parallel': 'true', 'hive.groupby.orderby.position.alias': 'true', 'hive.hadoop.supports.splittable.combineinputformat': 'true', 'hive.merge.size.per.task': '2048000000', 'hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize': '2048000000', 'hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names': 'false', 'mapred.min.split.size': '2048000000', 'mapred.max.split.size': '2048000000', 'mapred.map.tasks': '64', 'mapred.reduce.tasks': '64', 'mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize': '268435456', 'mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize': '536870912', 'mapreduce.job.reduces': '3000', 'mapreduce.map.memory.mb': '36864', 'mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb': '36864', 'mapreduce.map.child.java.opts': '-Xmx36864M', 'mapreduce.reduce.child.java.opts': '-Xmx36864M', 'mapreduce.map.java.opts': '-Xmx36864M', 'mapreduce.reduce.java.opts': '-Xmx36864M', 'mapreduce.task.timeout': '12000000', 'yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb': '20480', 'hive.exec.dynamic.partition': 'true', 'hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode': 'nonstrict'}, runAsync=True)
[2021-03-13 01:33:12.274 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _execute, 1006] Attempting to open transport (tries_left=3)
[2021-03-13 01:33:12.274 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _execute, 1008] Transport opened
[2021-03-13 01:33:13.326 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _log_response, 1034] ExecuteStatement: resp=TExecuteStatementResp(status=TStatus(statusCode=0, infoMessages=None, sqlState=None, errorCode=None, errorMessage=None), operationHandle=TOperationHandle(operationId=THandleIdentifier(guid=b'\xd0*\xba\xe2lQO+\x9c2\xfe\xb8]\xb0\xd0\x94', secret=b'\xa7D\xb8\xa4\x80F@\xca\x8fx\x10\x87\xfe\xa2\xa1\xd8'), operationType=0, hasResultSet=True, modifiedRowCount=None))
[2021-03-13 01:33:13.327 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _debug_log_state, 386] _execute_async: self._buffer=Batch() self._description=None self._last_operation_active=True self._last_operation=TOperationHandle(operationId=THandleIdentifier(guid=b'\xd0*\xba\xe2lQO+\x9c2\xfe\xb8]\xb0\xd0\x94', secret=b'\xa7D\xb8\xa4\x80F@\xca\x8fx\x10\x87\xfe\xa2\xa1\xd8'), operationType=0, hasResultSet=True, modifiedRowCount=None)
[2021-03-13 01:33:13.327 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, execute, 330] Waiting for query to finish
[2021-03-13 01:33:13.328 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _log_request, 1031] GetOperationStatus: req=TGetOperationStatusReq(operationHandle=TOperationHandle(operationId=THandleIdentifier(guid=b'\xd0*\xba\xe2lQO+\x9c2\xfe\xb8]\xb0\xd0\x94', secret=b'\xa7D\xb8\xa4\x80F@\xca\x8fx\x10\x87\xfe\xa2\xa1\xd8'), operationType=0, hasResultSet=True, modifiedRowCount=None))
[2021-03-13 01:33:13.328 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _execute, 1006] Attempting to open transport (tries_left=3)
[2021-03-13 01:33:13.328 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _execute, 1008] Transport opened
[2021-03-13 01:33:13.464 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _log_response, 1034] GetOperationStatus: resp=TGetOperationStatusResp(status=TStatus(statusCode=0, infoMessages=None, sqlState=None, errorCode=None, errorMessage=None), operationState=2, sqlState=None, errorCode=None, errorMessage=None, hasResultSet=True)
[2021-03-13 01:33:13.464 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _wait_to_finish, 410] _wait_to_finish: waited 0.13668107986450195 seconds so far
[2021-03-13 01:33:13.465 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, execute, 332] Query finished
[2021-03-13 01:33:13.465 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _log_request, 1031] GetOperationStatus: req=TGetOperationStatusReq(operationHandle=TOperationHandle(operationId=THandleIdentifier(guid=b'\xd0*\xba\xe2lQO+\x9c2\xfe\xb8]\xb0\xd0\x94', secret=b'\xa7D\xb8\xa4\x80F@\xca\x8fx\x10\x87\xfe\xa2\xa1\xd8'), operationType=0, hasResultSet=True, modifiedRowCount=None))
[2021-03-13 01:33:13.465 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _execute, 1006] Attempting to open transport (tries_left=3)
[2021-03-13 01:33:13.466 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _execute, 1008] Transport opened
[2021-03-13 01:33:13.559 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _log_response, 1034] GetOperationStatus: resp=TGetOperationStatusResp(status=TStatus(statusCode=0, infoMessages=None, sqlState=None, errorCode=None, errorMessage=None), operationState=2, sqlState=None, errorCode=None, errorMessage=None, hasResultSet=True)
[2021-03-13 01:33:13.560 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _wait_to_finish, 410] _wait_to_finish: waited 0.09481930732727051 seconds so far
[2021-03-13 01:33:13.560 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, fetchall, 534] Fetching all result rows
[2021-03-13 01:33:13.560 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, next, 580] next: buffer empty and op is active => fetching more data
[2021-03-13 01:33:13.561 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, description, 185] description=None has_result_set=True => getting schema
[2021-03-13 01:33:13.561 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _log_request, 1031] GetResultSetMetadata: req=TGetResultSetMetadataReq(operationHandle=TOperationHandle(operationId=THandleIdentifier(guid=b'\xd0*\xba\xe2lQO+\x9c2\xfe\xb8]\xb0\xd0\x94', secret=b'\xa7D\xb8\xa4\x80F@\xca\x8fx\x10\x87\xfe\xa2\xa1\xd8'), operationType=0, hasResultSet=True, modifiedRowCount=None))
[2021-03-13 01:33:13.561 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _execute, 1006] Attempting to open transport (tries_left=3)
[2021-03-13 01:33:13.561 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _execute, 1008] Transport opened
[2021-03-13 01:33:13.669 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _log_response, 1034] GetResultSetMetadata: resp=TGetResultSetMetadataResp(status=TStatus(statusCode=0, infoMessages=None, sqlState=None, errorCode=None, errorMessage=None), schema=TTableSchema(columns=[TColumnDesc(columnName='database_name', typeDesc=TTypeDesc(types=[TTypeEntry(primitiveEntry=TPrimitiveTypeEntry(type=7, typeQualifiers=None), arrayEntry=None, mapEntry=None, structEntry=None, unionEntry=None, userDefinedTypeEntry=None)]), position=1, comment='from deserializer')]))
[2021-03-13 01:33:13.669 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, get_result_schema, 1306] get_result_schema: schema=[('database_name', 'STRING', None, None, None, None, None)]
[2021-03-13 01:33:13.670 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _log_request, 1031] FetchResults: req=TFetchResultsReq(operationHandle=TOperationHandle(operationId=THandleIdentifier(guid=b'\xd0*\xba\xe2lQO+\x9c2\xfe\xb8]\xb0\xd0\x94', secret=b'\xa7D\xb8\xa4\x80F@\xca\x8fx\x10\x87\xfe\xa2\xa1\xd8'), operationType=0, hasResultSet=True, modifiedRowCount=None), orientation=0, maxRows=1024)
[2021-03-13 01:33:13.670 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _execute, 1006] Attempting to open transport (tries_left=3)
[2021-03-13 01:33:13.670 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _execute, 1008] Transport opened
[2021-03-13 01:38:29.662 US/Pacific; ERROR; impala.hiveserver2, _execute, 1016] Failed to open transport (tries_left=3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 1010, in _execute
return func(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thriftpy2/thrift.py", line 219, in _req
return self._recv(_api)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thriftpy2/thrift.py", line 238, in _recv
result.read(self._iprot)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thriftpy2/thrift.py", line 160, in read
iprot.read_struct(self)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thriftpy2/protocol/binary.py", line 387, in read_struct
return read_struct(self.trans, obj, self.decode_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thriftpy2/protocol/binary.py", line 316, in read_struct
read_val(inbuf, f_type, f_container_spec, decode_response))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thriftpy2/protocol/binary.py", line 289, in read_val
read_struct(inbuf, obj, decode_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thriftpy2/protocol/binary.py", line 316, in read_struct
read_val(inbuf, f_type, f_container_spec, decode_response))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thriftpy2/protocol/binary.py", line 289, in read_val
read_struct(inbuf, obj, decode_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thriftpy2/protocol/binary.py", line 316, in read_struct
read_val(inbuf, f_type, f_container_spec, decode_response))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thriftpy2/protocol/binary.py", line 256, in read_val
result.append(read_val(inbuf, v_type, v_spec, decode_response))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thriftpy2/protocol/binary.py", line 289, in read_val
read_struct(inbuf, obj, decode_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thriftpy2/protocol/binary.py", line 316, in read_struct
read_val(inbuf, f_type, f_container_spec, decode_response))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thriftpy2/protocol/binary.py", line 289, in read_val
read_struct(inbuf, obj, decode_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thriftpy2/protocol/binary.py", line 316, in read_struct
read_val(inbuf, f_type, f_container_spec, decode_response))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thriftpy2/protocol/binary.py", line 256, in read_val
result.append(read_val(inbuf, v_type, v_spec, decode_response))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thriftpy2/protocol/binary.py", line 230, in read_val
byte_payload = inbuf.read(sz)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thrift_sasl/init.py", line 173, in read
self._read_frame()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thrift_sasl/init.py", line 177, in _read_frame
header = self._trans_read_all(4)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thrift_sasl/init.py", line 198, in _trans_read_all
return read_all(sz)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thriftpy2/transport/socket.py", line 132, in read
message='TSocket read 0 bytes')
thriftpy2.transport.base.TTransportException: TTransportException(type=4, message='TSocket read 0 bytes')
[2021-03-13 01:38:29.664 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _execute, 1019] Closing transport (tries_left=3)
[2021-03-13 01:38:29.664 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _execute, 1006] Attempting to open transport (tries_left=2)
[2021-03-13 01:38:29.897 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _execute, 1008] Transport opened
[2021-03-13 01:38:30.077 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _log_response, 1034] FetchResults: resp=TFetchResultsResp(status=TStatus(statusCode=3, infoMessages=['org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Invalid OperationHandle: OperationHandle [opType=EXECUTE_STATEMENT, getHandleIdentifier()=d02abae2-6c51-4f2b-9c32-feb85db0d094]:12:11', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.OperationManager:getOperation:OperationManager.java:193', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService:fetchResults:CLIService.java:558', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService:FetchResults:ThriftCLIService.java:751', 'org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults:getResult:TCLIService.java:1717', 'org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults:getResult:TCLIService.java:1702', 'org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction:process:ProcessFunction.java:39', 'org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor:process:TBaseProcessor.java:39', 'org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor:process:TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56', 'org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess:run:TThreadPoolServer.java:286', 'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor:runWorker:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149', 'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker:run:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624', 'java.lang.Thread:run:Thread.java:748'], sqlState=None, errorCode=0, errorMessage='Invalid OperationHandle: OperationHandle [opType=EXECUTE_STATEMENT, getHandleIdentifier()=d02abae2-6c51-4f2b-9c32-feb85db0d094]'), hasMoreRows=None, results=None)
[2021-03-13 01:38:30.077 US/Pacific; ERROR; vale.sql._hive, retry_execute, 196] unknown error with impyla --- "impala.error.HiveServer2Error: Invalid OperationHandle: OperationHandle [opType=EXECUTE_STATEMENT, getHandleIdentifier()=d02abae2-6c51-4f2b-9c32-feb85db0d094]"
[2021-03-13 01:38:30.077 US/Pacific; INFO; impala.hiveserver2, close_operation, 292] Closing active operation
[2021-03-13 01:38:30.077 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _reset_state, 296] _reset_state: Resetting cursor state
[2021-03-13 01:38:30.077 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _log_request, 1031] CloseOperation: req=TCloseOperationReq(operationHandle=TOperationHandle(operationId=THandleIdentifier(guid=b'\xd0\xba\xe2lQO+\x9c2\xfe\xb8]\xb0\xd0\x94', secret=b'\xa7D\xb8\xa4\x80F@\xca\x8fx\x10\x87\xfe\xa2\xa1\xd8'), operationType=0, hasResultSet=True, modifiedRowCount=None))
[2021-03-13 01:38:30.078 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _execute, 1006] Attempting to open transport (tries_left=3)
[2021-03-13 01:38:30.078 US/Pacific; DEBUG; impala.hiveserver2, _execute, 1008] Transport opened
[2021-03-13 01:41:00.712 US/Pacific; ERROR; impala.hiveserver2, _execute, 1016] Failed to open transport (tries_left=3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vale/sql/_sql.py", line 254, in get_connection
yield conn
File "test_sql_hive_debug.py", line 27, in test_write_table
dbs = hive.get_databases()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vale/sql/_hive.py", line 242, in get_databases
z = self.read('SHOW DATABASES').fetchall()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vale/sql/_hive.py", line 239, in fetchall
return retry_execute(self.pyhive_client, super().fetchall)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vale/sql/_hive.py", line 182, in retry_execute
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vale/sql/_sql.py", line 141, in fetchall
return self._cursor.fetchall() # type: ignore
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 536, in fetchall
return list(self)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 584, in next
convert_types=self.convert_types)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 1266, in fetch
resp = self._rpc('FetchResults', req)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 995, in _rpc
err_if_rpc_not_ok(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 749, in err_if_rpc_not_ok
raise HiveServer2Error(resp.status.errorMessage)
impala.error.HiveServer2Error: Invalid OperationHandle: OperationHandle [opType=EXECUTE_STATEMENT, getHandleIdentifier()=d02abae2-6c51-4f2b-9c32-feb85db0d094]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```